# FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen streamcontroller not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am listening to  `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage`. print statement is working as expected but `streamController`  where I want to add `RemoteMessage` is not working.

```
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
    _streamController.add(message);
    print(message.notification?.body ?? 'empty body'); // working perfectly
        });
```

here is streamcontroller

```
 final StreamController<RemoteMessage> _streamController = StreamController();

  Stream<RemoteMessage> notificationStream() {
    return _streamController.stream;
  }
```

This is where I am listening to stream:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late Stream<RemoteMessage> _stream;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _stream = NotificationService().notificationStream();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) return Text(snapshot.data!.notification!.body!);
          return const Text('empty snapshot');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: in `initState` you create a new NotificationService, do you set up also the listening on `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen` when you create a NotificationService or is this also on an other position created too?

Comment: NotificationService is a Singleton it returns the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my singleton implementation. I changed it to

```
class NotificationService {
  NotificationService._();
  static final NotificationService instance = NotificationService._();
  ...
  ...
}
```